# Object did not collide with other object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, physics, game-physics

I am working on POOL TABLE game in Unity.

I am applying force to the cueBall to when we hit with stick. And it's working fine cueBall hit's the other ball and move as per physics.

But when we add some more force then the cueBall did not collide with any ball. Also some time the cueBall goes out of the table.

I don't know why this happen.

Can anyone tell me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: It sounds like you're experiencing tunnelling issues. What are your physics and collision detection settings?

Comment: It sounds like a "Bullet through paper" problem, to me (not sure if @Bart refers to the same issue).

Comment: Yep @BiG. We're describing the same thing.

Comment: Maybe [How to collide objects with high speed in Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326535/how-to-collide-objects-with-high-speed-in-unity/14387936#14387936) is helpful